# Can in a relational data model, a single column have multiple data types?

Tags: sql

I had this question, in one assignment, and the answer is false. Can someone explain cuz I saw couple questions here trying to do this

Comment: Why should that be possible, and how? Is this maybe specific to any database system?

Comment: I heard about sql_variant data type that allows this

Comment: @FandomoftheOpera . . . One could argue that a `sql_variant` is really a type that happens to be able to represent values of other types.  The question is ambiguous, but the answer is "no" because a column has to be defined with exactly one type specification, even if it is a "super type".

Comment: How would you even index a column like that? Well, the idea of an index does make sense in this special case... unless you index the byte codes; but again, that doesn't have too much value, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most SQL databases, this is not strictly possible.  However, there are a few exceptions.  In SQLite, any type of data can be stored in any column.  However, SQLite columns support the concept of "affinity."  There are 5 affinity types, including `TEXT`, `NUMERIC`, `INTEGER`, `REAL`, and `BLOB`.  Inserting numeric data into a column with a `TEXT` affinity will result in that data first being converted to text.

On other databases, such as MySQL, columns do have rigid types, but there are flexibilities in other ways.  For example, MySQL supports implicit casting such that the following comparison against a numeric column `col` is allowed and possible:

```sql
WHERE col > '123'
```

In this case, MySQL will implicitly convert the string literal `123` to an integer before doing the comparison.

Comment: I would argue against the idea of implicit casting. I've seen so many bugs in the code that remain hidden for eons because of poor design decisions that are promoted by implicit casting. Well... just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

A column value is an atomic value.

A single atomic value has exactly one data type: the declared for the column that contains the value.

So the answer is: no, a column in a relational database (that honors the SQL standard) can not have multiple data types.

Comment: Not strictly true in SQLite, [see here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: well, SQLite doesn't really have data types to begin with - everything is a string there.